# can multiple producers send message to Queue at the same time from different java applications

Tags: java, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have 2 applications A and B, trying to send messages from both to one queue.
Placed a while loop at both places which is sending message to queue.
if i start application A and start while loop it starts sending message to queue and consumer consumes message sent from A, now at same time if i start while loop from B application it doesn't publish messages to queue as consumer doesn't consumes any message sent from B.

So can someone clear the doubt if messages are being sent at same time from multiple producers to single queue or not.

PS- using IBM queue and using a single consumer.

Comment: B is not getting any error and yes both are running in different java instances.

Comment: Does it hang? What version of mq jars are in use.  What version of mq is the qmgr?

Comment: using JMS, spring-jms-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: using convertAndSend method.

Comment: What `com.ibm.mq*.jar` version after you using?  Are both producers the same? Is it possible B is configured with a transacted session and is not doing a commit,  this would mean messages are not available to the consumer.

Comment: To answer your direct question - yes, you can have two different applications sending messages to a queue at the same time. As to why your setup doesn't achieve that, I think perhaps you need to show us some code - both producing code and consuming code.

Comment: @MoragHughson do you have any link or document which says the same ?

Comment: @JoshMc - Specification-Version: 7.5.0.7
Producers are different, placed at different applications.

Comment: @MoragHughson - which part of code you want see ?

Comment: Hi All,
Actually it is producing messages from both process at the same time. it was happening very quickly as i had used while loop, hence logger was not updating. I provided delay and cheked then i found it is publishing the messages. thanks @MoragHughson

Comment: You are running a very old version of the software on the sender side, MQ 7.5 went out of support almost two years ago (April 30 2018). IBM for a cost will provide extended support for an additional three years, so maybe you fall in that group. The 7.5.0.7 maintenance release itself came out in September 9th 2016, so it is almost four years old at this point. I would strongly suggest you move to a newer version.

Comment: Note that MQ v8.0 went out of support April 30 2020, and MQ v9.0 goes out of support September 30 2021. When you do migrate you should go with either 9.1 which has no announced end of support (they give five years minimum so it could be 2023) or go with the next version of MQ that should be out some time later this year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can have multiple producers for single queue.
Multiple producers can also publish messages at the same time.